# Differnetiable function f on open and contiguous subset of R^n, Show that f is constant on U

Tags: functional-analysis

$f$ is a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$. $U$ is an open and contiguous subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The Derivative of $f$ disappears on $U$.

I know what contiguous mean, namely that for every two points $p,q \in U$ there exists a curve on which both points lie.
Since the derivative disappears I would just assume the function is constant as I am not aware of  another function with derivative $0$, that is not constant. I feel like I haven't grasped the  question yet.

Comment: Hint: Apply the mean-value inequality.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is just any open set the conclusion fails. For example if $f=0$ on $(0,1)$ and $1$ on $(1,2)$ then $f'=0$ in $U =(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ But $f$ is not a constant. I suppose 'curve' here is intended to mean a continuous curve. In that case the assumption makes $U$ a path connected, hence connected open set. In this case it is true that $f$ is a constant on $U$.